# Como puedo sumar un resultado anterior en mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos

Tengo un pequeño problema con MySql, necesito sumar un registro anterior para calcular aforo en un centro comercial, no entiendo muy bien la formula que hay que realizar, si es que pueden ayudarme, sería genial!

```
select sum(enterNum) Entradas, sum(exitNum) Salidas, sum(enterNum - exitNum) Aforo, horacross
from detalle_personas
where fechacross = curdate()
group by horacross
```

Acá en la imagen se ve lo que tengo, pero, necesito que el 7 que está en aforo tenga en lugar de un 7 un 10, ya que se suma el registro anterior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Adjunto imagen completa de la tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de MySQL usas?

Comment: Podrías publicar la estructura de la tabla original?

Comment: Listo!!, ahí está

Answer (score 0):

Hice una consulta similar hace un tiempo en "Database Administrators" así que la dejo acá como [referencia](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/295130/inconsistent-results-between-mysql-and-mariadb-when-using-variables-and-order).

Para poder sumar el valor del resultado *anterior* tenés que usar *variables*. El problema (y es el motivo por el cual surgió mi pregunta), es que las operaciones las necesitás hacer en orden y la tabla se ordena *después* de ejecutar la consulta, NO *durante*. Por eso es necesario hacer una *subconsulta* que traiga los resultados en orden (ahí ya se calculan los parciales por hora) y el *aforo* se calcula a partir de esos resultados ya ordenados.

```sql
SET @aforo = 0;

SELECT
  `Entradas`,
  `Salidas`,
  @aforo := (@aforo + `Entradas` - `Salidas`) `Aforo`,
  `horacross`
FROM (
  SELECT
    SUM(`enterNum`) `Entradas`,
    SUM(`exitNum`) `Salidas`,
    `horacross`
  FROM `detalle_personas`
  WHERE `fechacross` = CURDATE()
  GROUP BY `horacross`
  ORDER BY `horacross`
) `parciales`
```

Te dejo un [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c3571252602903cf152b4f4530ab4860) para que lo pruebes.